# How to approach the questions of projectile motion in which two objects rebound in air?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, collision, projectile, elasticity, models

I have tried multiple ways but failed several times so can anyone plz guide me about this.

Comment: stack exchange is more about learning and understanding concepts than homework related question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about two projectiles colliding in mid-air, then the equations for projectile motion can give you conditions just before the collision. Then you need to know things about the collision: Does it conserve energy?  Can it be described in 2D or do you need to go to 3? Do you have any information about the final velocities? A 3D collision will conserve momentum in each of three directions.

Answer (score -1):

Think of projectile motion as 2 individual motions, one along x-axis and one along the y-axis. Now if you are saying that the balls are rebounding, make an apparent graph of the motion in x-axis and y-axis and then solve it using basic laws of motion like you do in 1D and write the x-axis part in î and y-axis part in j cap.